# How does Community ask questions

Tags: discussion, community-user

[Community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is "background process", so how does it ask questions? Bot can't ask such questions, so who runs this account? For example,  [November 2011 Community Moderator Election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111310/november-2011-community-moderator-election).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the community asking questions"?

Comment: @Mysticial it seems quite clear to me. The community user is listed as the OP of that question.

Comment: @DannyBeckett That link was ninja edited in. It wasn't there initially. Now it's clear.

Comment: @Mysticial those pesky ninjas!

Comment: The Community account still is an account. So I don't really know what the confusing issue is here.

Comment: I think the real question here is, who runs the community account? Obviously it's at least partially a bot, but there if there are posts that community has authored, someone - probably SE staff - posts under the account.

Comment: @NeilFein Agree with you. I'll edit my question

Comment: I personally dream that someone just runs some SQL to put the proper rows in the proper tables. And thus is a question created from nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Community Manager (usually Grace Note) asks those questions. They manually change the user ID in the database to give credit to the Community user afterwards, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

The Community user just has a specific user ID. Certain automatic actions on the sites are performed with that user ID.